# Does/Can/Should subsonic natively handle database collisions?

Tags: subsonic3, data-access-layer, collision-detection

I have recently picked up SubSonic to use in a new vb.net windows app project and so far I really love it! Its a perfect start and written in a way, using t4 templates, which leaves it wide open to customisation.

Anyway, I'm using Active record and MySql. I have a form whose controls are databound to a subsonic dataclass using a bindingsource. 
When I:

1. make some changes in the form BUT
2. also change the data in the db table using the MySql workbench and then
3. save the changes through the form

I get no warning/notification of the data collision? 
The workbench change is overwritten by calling Save() on the subsonic dataclass

This may not be a feature of subsonic yet or am I doing somthing wrong?
If not I will add to the save code in the templates, so that I:

1. load a fresh copy the record
2. compare the existing record's timestamp to the fresh record's timestamp
3. compare each field's data and build a collection of changes
4. raise an event, with the changes collection in the eventargs so that I can get the user to decide wht to do.

I dont want to do this if its already done, thats all.

Answer (score 0):

> I get no warning/notification of the
>   data collision? The workbench change
>   is overwritten by calling Save() on
>   the subsonic dataclass
>
> This may not be a feature of subsonic
>   yet or am I doing somthing wrong?

There are no optimistic concurrency features in SubSonic.  Also, it is not "yet", it is "period" - there is no significant development occurring in the SubSonic project, and what development there is revolves around supporting Oracle (a goal that has long been unrealized).

> If not I will add to the save code in
>   the templates

I'm going to suggest that it will be more efficient for you to drop SubSonic and begin learning a different data access tool with more robust features, like Entity Framework or NHibernate.  This will not likely be the last limitation you encounter with SubSonic.

> If not I will add to the save code in
>   the templates, so that I:
>
> 1. load a fresh copy the record
> 2. compare the existing record's timestamp to the fresh record's timestamp
> 3. compare each field's data and build a collection of changes
> 4. raise an event, with the changes collection in the eventargs so that I can get the user to decide wht to do.

It would be unnecessarily inefficient to begin by loading a fresh copy of the record. A better alternative would be to add a where clause to the update for the timestamp column so that the update will only occur if both the primary key and timestamp column match.  You can detect a concurrency violation in this manner by checking the affected record count.  If the affected record count is zero, the record has been updated or deleted, and then you can load a copy and begin conflict resolution.

Comment: Thanks qes, for the input on concurrency violation, will certainly head in that direction. I'm not ready to ditch subsonic yet as I read a question on this site 'Is Subsonic Dying' and Rob gave a pretty convincing answer.

Comment: It's not dying, it does what it does. What functionality it has is perfectly usable.  But you won't find much help with concurrency or managing relationships between objects, and no new features of that sort are likely to be added.  As Rob will say, it's a query tool, not an ORM.